# Search and update the value of custom object member in Powershell

Tags: powershell

How to update a specific member of custom object by searching for a value from another member.

For example: If I want to update RAM=16 for the ServerName= 'blabla2' with cmdlet similar to $hashtable.Set_Item($currentKey,'NewValue') that can search and update values for specific key in hash table.

The custom object in question is a large object with more 100k thousand lines of members, so looking for an efficient solution to search and update the member.

```
$serverList= @() 
$serverList+= @{ServerName= 'blabla1'; OSType='Windows XP'; RAM='3'}
$serverList+= @{ServerName= 'blabla2'; OSType='Windows XP Profesional'; RAM='3'}


#Write-Output $serverList

#display as table
$serverList | % { new-object PSObject -Property $_}
```